# Shell script to find what package provides a file on OpenBSD

Tags: shell-script, ksh, openbsd

```
# for i in `pkg_info -q`; do pkg_info -L "$i" | grep ^/ | sed "s/^/$i/g" | perl -pe 's/\//\t\//'; done | grep tasklist.desktop
xfce4-panel-4.10.0p2    /usr/local/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/tasklist.desktop
# pkg_file() { for i in `pkg_info -q`; do pkg_info -L "$i" | grep ^/ | sed "s/^/$i/g" | perl -pe 's/\//\t\//'; done | grep $1; } 
ksh: syntax error: `{' unexpected
#
```

**Q:** what am I missing? I just want to put in the .profile file, but when I put the line in a function I got the shown error

Comment: Really, you get this error even after correcting the syntax? What's before that line?

Comment: The function declaration works for me for ksh on OpenBSD.  When I run it grep gives me usage information and then it seems to hang.  Have you tried it since correcting the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition syntax is wrong -- it's `foo() {}`, not `foo {}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use existing tools. The `pkglocate` command from [pkglocatedb](http://ports.su/databases/pkglocatedb) package can let you search all files from any OpenBSD package, no matter do you have it installed or not:

```
$ pkglocate /usr/local/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/tasklist.desktop
xfce4-panel-4.10.1:x11/xfce4/xfce4-panel:/usr/local/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/tasklist.desktop
```

You can search through only installed packages with [pkg_info(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pkg_info&sektion=1):

```
$ pkg_info -qE /usr/local/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/tasklist.desktop
xfce4-panel-4.10.1
```